# How to integrate with a built-in Azure Databricks Hive Metastore?

Tags: azure-databricks, hive-metastore

We need to transition out Hive Metastore from Trino AKS deployment onto the Databricks.
When running the Hive Metastore as a standalone / separate container it is easy to integrate with it, as we have the endpoint URL readily available:

thrift://our-hive-metastore-endpoint:8093

However it is not at all obvious for us how to determine the corresponding Hive Metastore endpoint for the Databrick-based metastore.

Does anyone know how to determine this endpoint in Azure Databricks?

Comment: what do you want to integrate with it? In general, built-in hive metastore isn't reachable from other apps (without hacks). You can of course configure external hive metastore